# Why the id of an object would change depending on the line in the python shell

Tags: windows, python-3.x, interpreter

This questions is  just out of curiosity.

While I was reading the [python's object model documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#index-35), I decided to experiment a little with the id of a class method and found this behavior:

```
 Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  4 2011, 09:07:29) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
 Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
 >>> class A():
    def a(self):
        pass


 >>> id(A().a)
 54107080
 >>> id(A().a)
 54108104
 >>> id(A().a)
 54107080
 >>> id(A().a)
 54108104
 >>> 
 >>> id(A().a)
 54108104
 >>> 
 >>> id(A().a)
 54108104
 >>> id(A().a)
 54107080
 >>>
```

The id of the method changes with the parity of the line!

I actually wanted to create a couple of instances of the same class and see if they had the same method object, and I expected that they would be the exact same one, or change every time, what I did not expect was that the method id would be related with the interpreter line being even or not! Any ideas?

Note: I know that there is a mismatch of version from the docs and the interpreter, it just happens that I'm on windows and I have only 3.2 installed

Comment: I can't replicate this with 2.7.3, 3.2.3, or 3.3.0 on Mac, so either it's particular to 3.2.2, or more likely has something to do with the Windows implementation...

Comment: I just tried on 2.6.8, 2.7.3, and 3.3.0 on linux (Arch) and got the same id, so I guess you're right, it is a windows implementation detail, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain wat the line `id(A().a)` does:

```
A() # creates a new object I call a
```

Then

```
A().a # creates a function f bound to a
A.a.__get__(A(), A) # same as above

>>> A.a.__get__(A(), A)
<bound method A.a of <__main__.A object at 0x02D85550>>
>>> A().a
<bound method A.a of <__main__.A object at 0x02D29410>>
```

This bound function is always another because it has another object in `__self__`

```
>>> a = A()
>>> assert a.a.__self__ is a
```

`__self__` will be passed as first argument `self` to the function A.a

EDIT: This is what it looks like:

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> class A:
    def a(self):
        pass


>>> id(A().a)
43476312
>>> id(A().a)
49018760
```

Here the id repeats like abab

```
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  4 2011, 09:51:08) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> class A:
    def a(self):
        pas
        s


>>> id(A().a)
50195512
>>> id(A().a)
50195832
>>> id(A().a)
50195512
>>> id(A().a)
50195832
```

EDIT: For linux or what is not my machine and whatsoever I do not know

```
id(A().a)
```

will always give the same result except if you store this to a variable.
I do not know why but I would think that it is because of performance optimization.
For objects on the stack you do not need to allocate new space for an object every time you call a function.

Comment: So how do you explain not being able to replicate the behavior?

Comment: I would only guess that you allocate the same ressources again and again or maybe you just did `A.a` instead of `A().a`

Comment: It should be bound 'method', not 'function'. They're different types.

Comment: @User - no, I ran exactly what the OP listed, using the versions in my comment above, as well as 3.3.0 on XP, but I couldn't replicate his results. I could replicate your code just fine, though.

Comment: When you repeatedly create and destroy objects like that, the addresses can cycle either based on contention in a small-object memory pool or, similarly, for objects taken from freelists that are used by built-in types. These strategies minimize the performance hit of frequent `malloc`/`free` calls. Try running a `gc.collect()`, which clears many of the freelists, including the one used for method objects.