# Strange behaviour related to apparent caching of "{}"

Tags: python

Today I learned that Python caches the expression `{}`, and replaces it with a new empty dict when it's assigned to a variable:

```
print id({})
# 40357936

print id({})
# 40357936

x = {}
print id(x)
# 40357936

print id({})
# 40356432
```

I haven't looked at the source code, but I have an idea as to how this might be implemented. (Maybe when the reference count to the global `{}` is incremented, the global `{}` gets replaced.)

But consider this bit:

```
def f(x):
    x['a'] = 1
    print(id(x), x)

print(id(x))
# 34076544

f({})
# (34076544, {'a': 1})

print(id({}), {})
# (34076544, {})

print(id({}))
# 34076544
```

`f` modifies the global dict without causing it to be replaced, and it prints out the modified dict. But outside of `f`, despite the id being the same, the global dict is now empty!

**What is happening??**

Comment: you might be also interested in that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315096/why-the-id-of-an-object-would-change-depending-on-the-line-in-the-python-shell/15321863#15321863

Comment: Very cool edge case, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Python's `id()` uses a memory address (in at least the CPython implementation) as an ID for objects. It's a unique identifier only at a single point in time, not unique over your program's entire lifetime. This is explicit in the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id

Comment: Note that this is very implementation-dependent: calling `id()` four times as in your first example gives me different values in PyPy (where they dropped by 16 after the first), and in both Jython and IronPython (where they increased by one each time).

Comment: @DSM You're right, it's entirely implementation-dependent. The *exact* values are even worse than that though: On CPython and with the default PyPy configuration, the values are the memory address and can vary between *identical runs of the same program*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not being cached -- if you don't assign the result of `{}` anywhere, its reference count is 0 and it's cleaned up right away. It just happened that the next one you allocated reused the memory from the old one.  When you assign it to `x` you keep it alive, and then the next one has a different address.

In your function example, once `f` returns there are no remaining references to your dict, so it gets cleaned up too, and the same thing applies.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for explaining away that "caching" (which I thought was kind of a fairly dubious optimization, anyway)

Answer (score 4):

Python isn't doing any caching here.  There are two possibilities when `id()` gives the same return value at different points in a program:

1. `id()` was called on the same object twice
2. The first object that `id()` was called on was garbage collected before the second object was created, and the second object was created in the same memory location as the original

In this case, it was the second one.  This means that even though `print id({}); print id({})` may print the same value twice, each call is on a distinct object.